# Adding data into Date datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to update a date field in a table that's of type DATE with data from DateTimePicker control

I changed the format of the control as updated the table as shown below

```
dtp1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtp1.CustomFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"

query = "INSERT INTO student_attendance_table(regno,date,year,batch) VALUES('1138M0343', " & dtp1.Text & ",  " & year & ",  " & batch & ")"
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

But the table is not getting updated. Instead showing the following error

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: Please use sql parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Can you explain more on what you just said. I can't understand

Comment: Maybe try dtp1.Value instead of dtp1.Text?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Is this line correct? `dtp1.CustomFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
' " & dtp1.Text & " '
```

Forgot to put the single quotation

Comment: This is what marc_s, and Brad M were talking about. You where concatenating your SQL statement together when you did not have the single quotations. That left your statement vulnerable to SQL injection.